# How to install Ubuntu Core to x86 (actually ARMv7) architecture board (BPi-M1)?

Tags: 32-bit, arm

I have Banana Pi (BPi-M1) with Allwinner A20 SoC,
[this one](http://www.bananapi.org/p/product.html)

(ARM Cortex-A7 dual-core, 1GHz, Mali400MP2 GPU)

But in this manual,
[here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/#try-x86),
about starting on x86 architecture there are note:

> We only generate and certify images which work on a 64 bit system. If you require 32 bit, You can generate the image using `ubuntu-device-flash`.

But I couldn't find manual how to generate this image.

Comment: As I can understand, I need rootfs image from Ubuntu Core for 32-bit system (like for [Raspberry Pi 2](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/)), and then build image for my banana like [that](http://www.bananapi.org/p/blog-page_20.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title contradicts your question, ARM is not x86, they are two different architectures, you need Ubuntu for ARM not x86.

As you use Banana pi specifically, you can take your pick of images for that device [on there website](http://www.banana-pi.org/download.html).

The Ubuntu versions available are [Lubuntu](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzoTh3Vdt47fflJ2RVZSV3pNQTRpYS1BMWhrSWdaLThzc2lYem5tT1RZUk4tbEN2VHFCdEE&usp=drive_web) and [Ubuntu](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzoTh3Vdt47fflZfYzZPQWxDZXRRMDFRREVhenlrV1BhRHNkaVFFaGsyYTc3R3V2YkdmR1U&usp=drive_web), no versions are given on the page but the Ubuntu at least is 15.04 and that may be an issue but there are many more distributions to choose from.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If this was the answer you are looking for please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and let others find the correct answer, if no, please say why.

Comment: True, now I see my stupidness.

I meant 32-bit system.. How I can generate this image?

Comment: You don't generate an image, on the site I gave you are a load of pre made images for your device, snappy core won't work on ARM, it is for x86_64 PCs only.

Comment: But how about [that](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/)? Raspberry Pi 2 also have ARMv7 multicore processor.

Comment: I already install Lubuntu image, but want more effective using resources.

I saw [manual](http://www.bananapi.org/p/blog-page_20.html), how to build image for my banana, but I need the rootfs package of  Ubuntu Core for 32-bit system.. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, I have been busy. Yes it seems you need rootfs from a ARM package, as it happens, I found one for you that may meet your needs, see http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/daily-preinstalled/current/ for a v7 image.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

I already get http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/14.04/release/, armhf, but don't know differences.